# How to create Kafka Partitions using Java Code

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I am trying to create **Kafka Partition**  using **JAVA.**  But didn't succeed.

Can anyone give me some example, how to create partition in kafka using Java code.

Answer (score 2):

It's not very clear what you mean. If you are trying to increase the number of partitions of an existing topic, the method to use is AdminClient.[createPartitions](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#createPartitions-java.util.Map-org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.CreatePartitionsOptions-).

If the topic doesn't exist yet, you can use AdminClient.[createTopics](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/AdminClient.html#createTopics-java.util.Collection-org.apache.kafka.clients.admin.CreateTopicsOptions-), which takes the partition count as field in the [NewTopic](https://kafka.apache.org/11/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/admin/NewTopic.html) object.

Comment: :- I topic doesn't exist yet. I am trying to create new topic with partition through java code.